# etree.iterwalk doesn't walk through the processing instructions since lxml v4.4

Tags: python, lxml, processing-instruction

Before [lxml](https://lxml.de/) v4.4, [lxml.etree.iterwalk](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.iterwalk-class.html) walks through elements **and** processing instructions:

With the following code:

```py
from lxml import etree

XML = """<root>
  <?page no="1"?>
  <element key='value'>text</element>
  <element>text</element>tail<?page no="2"?>
  <empty-element xmlns="http://testns/"/>
</root>"""

context = etree.iterwalk(etree.XML(XML), events=("start",))
for action, elem in context:
    if isinstance(elem, etree._ProcessingInstruction):
        print(f"{action}: {elem.target} {elem.text}")
    else:
        print(f"{action}: {elem.tag}")
```

I had:

```
start: root
start: page no="1"
start: element
start: element
start: page no="2"
start: {http://testns/}empty-element
```

But since lxml v4.4 and above, I have:

```
start: root
start: element
start: element
start: {http://testns/}empty-element
```

Processing instructions are now ignored. Why?

How can I restore the previous behavior?

Comment: Looks like `"pi"` is now considered a separate event type for processing instructions, just add that to your `events=` list.

Comment: It works. Where have you found this information? Not documented?

Comment: I couldn't find any relevant documentation, I took a look at the `etree` source code and saw a use of this new event type in an internal call to `iterwalk()`.  (There's a "comment" event type, too, that I don't think is documented either.)

Comment: @jasonharper, can you post an answer so that I accept it?